# Java : Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am getting the following error when trying to run java with 1G memory.

```
C:\>java -verbose -Xmx1G
```

When I run it, I receive the following message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

It is working fine with max memory set to 768M. I am using Java 7 (build 1.7.0_15-b03).

Here is my system's info

```
Total Physical Memory:     3,510 MB
Available Physical Memory: 2,393 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  2,048 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 1,965 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    83 MB
OS: Windows XP.
```

Comment: Have you tried 1000M (which is 1G)? may be Java doesn't understand 1G

Comment: Like sanbhat said, try running with: -XX:MaxHeapSize=1024m

Comment: But if that was the problem, the error message would have said so ...

Comment: Like this: `Unrecognized option: -xmx2G`

Comment: i have tried -XX:MaxHeapSize=1024m and i tried with -Xmx1024M also. both cases the issue remains.

Comment: Did the BIOS settings change (AGP Aperture size) or something other that may reduce the avialable address space? Also, did you change the garbage collector? (The GC may reserve some additional memory).

Answer (score 1):

The heap does not only depend on the available RAM or physical memory. The maximum theoretical heap limit for the 32-bit JVM is 4G. Due to various additional constraints such as available swap, kernel address space usage, memory fragmentation, and VM overhead, in practice the limit can be much lower.

Comment: it was working on the same machine 2 days back. can i got some more pointers, so that i can see which param or configuration change lead to this issue. i have tried changing the virtual memory setting also and increased it to 3.5GB and restarted my machine and tried. That also did not work

Comment: I ran into this issue when I upgraded from Java 6 to Java 7.  I had 1GB of heap configured before and now with Java 7 it only works if I lower the heap size.  I guess the new version of Java uses more memory itself.